# Send first word to last position in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with SURNAME NAME as value. I would need to invert that, getting NAME SURNAME as result. I've been taking a look at php functions but couldn't find a useful one. Thank you!

```
$name = array('SMITH JOHN', 'BACON KEVIN', 'MERCURY FREDDIE');
```

Comment: And you don't have any ``William Henry Gates III`` (or similar) in the list?

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```
$names = array('SMITH JOHN', 'BACON KEVIN', 'MERCURY FREDDIE');
foreach ($names as &$full_name){ //Remember here to pass by reference &
  $parts = explode(" ", $full_name);
  $full_name = "{$parts[1]} {$parts[0]}" ;
}

var_dump($names) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$names = preg_replace('/^(\S+)\s+(\S+)$/', '\2 \1', $names);
```

**edit:** Yep, it works [just fine](http://ideone.com/usnPLE).

Please note that this only works for two-part names.  If it has more than two parts (e.g. middle name, suffix) it will leave it as-is.

Answer (score 1):

```
$name = array('SMITH JOHN', 'BACON KEVIN', 'MERCURY FREDDIE');
array_walk(
    $name,
    function (&$value) {
        $value = implode(' ',array_reverse(explode(' ',$value)));
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jan pointed out, string parsing is the way to go (take the individual string and parse the parts to compose the new string) but just be warned in general you'll need to make assumptions about the names to do this correctly.

If you're *guaranteed* to have only `LAST FIRST` entries, you're fine.

But for example, what about names like

```
HENRY VAN WINKLE
MADONNA
CATHERINE ZETA-JONES
ROBERT DOWNEY JR.
MR. T
```

Some cases are clear, but others aren't.